# Running Django written with python3 in Gunicorn

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, gunicorn

I've written a django site in python 3.2 and I want to run it by Gunicorn in my VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 OS and I faced errors for that belongs to python 2.7 but since it's not a good idea to change my default python to 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 I want to ask is there anyway to tell Gunicorn to run my project by python 3.2 not python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, install the other python, but don't change your ubuntu settings. When you create your virtualenv for your django project, use the -p flag to specify which python to use.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.2 [path/to/new/virtualenv/]
```

Alternatively, move the whole project to Heroku. There you can specify things such as python version, plus you can start ignoring a whole bunch of dev-ops stuff like this and spend more time writing your app. It's free, and you can get set up in a couple of hours.

Comment: This is a precursor. You need the virtualenv sure, but you will still have big problems because the eventlet or gevent workers required by gunicorn are not python 3 compatible. I've had to give up on using Python 3 because of this problem :(